# Is it possible to craft a non-null string in PHP that is a null password in LDAP?

Tags: php, null, ldap, bind

LDAP server, PHP, and not allowing null passwords.

My code currently checks password for boolean true (yes, I will exclude some values that might be valid non-null LDAP passwords, such as `"0"`) to avoid allowing blank password logins with LDAP.  But is this enough?

Is it possible to create a value that PHP will consider non-null but will be treated as a blank password by LDAP? perhaps a string with `0x0` (empty C-string) or some other such hackerish monstrosity?

using [`ldap_bind()`](http://php.net/ldap_bind)

Comment: I'd say you need to test that against your ldap server. It might behave differently. Probably you can define a constraint of what a valid password is (covering also character encodings) so you can just define that `"\0"` (PHP string, NUL character) is not valid?

Comment: how about if you just restrict your passwords to always start with a letter?

Comment: @AntonSoradoi I don't make the LDAP/password policy. I'd just like to use our existing infrastructure for authentication for some web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possibilities covered by the LDAP standard regarding simple BIND operations and one possibility not addressed by the standard:

1. null DN and null password. No authentication takes place. This is commonly known as "anonymous" and is the initial state of a connection.
2. DN and null password. No authentication takes place.
3. DN and password. Authentication takes place and either fails or succeeds. If authentication succeeds, a zero (0) result code is returned in the BIND response. Otherwise a non-zero result code is returned in the BIND response.

And lastly, not addressed by the LDAP standard:

1. no DN and a non-null password. No authentication takes place. The directory server should reject this BIND operation.

What the server does for the first two depends on the configuration of the server but since no authentication takes place the BIND operation should be rejected if the server is properly configured.